# Opencv and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I am trying to use Opencv in the environment of Visual Studio 2010. My computer is 64 bit and I use vs 2010 64 bit too. I searched many tutorials on how to configure opencv in vs 2010. However, I could not succeed. 
There is a video about compile and configure the vs 2010 and opencv
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBhwbRoKvk
I got couple of errors such as:
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tbb/tbb_stddef.h': No such file or directory    C:\SeniorProject\OPENCV2.1\include\opencv\cvinternal.h  131 1   cxcore

Error   2   error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\cxcore210d.lib'    C:\SeniorProject\OPENCV2.1\build\tests\cxts\LINK    cxts
Error   4   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tbb/tbb_stddef.h': No such file or directory    c:\seniorproject\opencv2.1\include\opencv\cvinternal.h  131 1   ml

Error   7   error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\cxcore210d.lib'    C:\SeniorProject\OPENCV2.1\build\apps\haartraining\LINK haartraining
Error   8   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tbb/tbb_stddef.h': No such file or directory    c:\seniorproject\opencv2.1\include\opencv\cvinternal.h  131 1   mltest
Error   9   error LNK1104: cannot open file '....\lib\Debug\cxcore210d.lib'    C:\SeniorProject\OPENCV2.1\build\apps\haartraining\LINK performance
Error   16  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tbb/tbb_stddef.h': No such file or directory    c:\seniorproject\opencv2.1\include\opencv\cvinternal.h  131 1   traincascade

Other errors are same as above. I tried to do a project on opencv in c++ and I am told to do in the vs 2011. I am using opencv 2.1 not 2.2 Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual C++ you need to tell the compiler where to look for the OpenCV LIBRARIES and headers.
Looks like the compiler cannot find the libraries.

OR
According to:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B

a) OpenCV 2.1 has problems in 64 bit configuration, upgrade.
b) As the above link suggests, build the Libraries on your system using CMake and Visual Studio, in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure using CMake (as stated by Ouspoken). Get OpenCV 2.2 and try the following [step by step guide](http://kaushalsolanki.com/2011/01/compile-and-set-up-opencv-for-visual-studio-2010-with-64-bits-support-ipp-7-0-and-tbb/).

If you are using the latest versions of IPP/TBB from Intel, you would have to modify the CMake file a bit (am sure/hope it will be fixed soon).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to check your system processes, there are several MSBUILD.exe running even you close the MS Visual studio. After you kill the process, and try to rebuild again, it shall work.

Answer (score 0):

You may also follow this video here, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZvjTTK9zTw. It shows how to setup opencv 2.3.1 in MS Visual studio 2010. It does have directive intructions on how to go about this, you should not experience major problems.